# How to load a dataset(.npz) locally in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

I'm working on a handwritten didgits recognition project. I need to load the data from mnist dataset. My problem is that I can't use the `load_data()` function because when it starts downloading the dataset, it returns an error:

`URL fetch failure on https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/mnist.npz: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`

Here is the piece of code that I use:

```
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```

I downloaded the `mnist.npz` file using device that has access to the directory. How can I use the file locally instead of loading it?

This is what I tried:
`(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.utils.get_file(os.path.abspath('mnist.npz'), origin='', extract=True)`

It returned an error: `too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Comment: Have you read this [TF documentation page](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/numpy)?

Comment: Yes. Here it says that source is not important. Since I can't access the URL path, I 'tried `file://C:/Users/.../mnist.npz`. It says: `The system cannot find the path specified: ' '`. Even though it starts downloading from the local path that I've specified.

Comment: Did u check if the path exists with "os.path.existst(MY_PATH)" after "import os"? Maybe there are some typos.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem by doing this:

1. I downloaded the dataset and placed it in the same directory with the script.
2. I tried lots of ways to load the data from the dataset, but most of them either kept downloading the data from internet, or didn't want to load the data from the local dataset for some reasons. The method that worked looks like this:

```
path = 'C:/Users/.../mnist.npz'  #full path to the dataset
with np.load(path, allow_pickle=True) as f:
    x_train, y_train = f['x_train'], f['y_train']
    x_test, y_test = f['x_test'], f['y_test']
```

At the end I have the `x_train, y_train` and `x_test, y_test` variables. Just what I needed. Hope someone will find this helpful.